# Show that the limit of the following sequence converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Find the limit of the following sequence $\int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx$ where $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Let $I_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x)dx$.

Let us take $F'(x) = f(x),\forall x \in [0,1].$[This holds by the First fundamental theorem of calculus and also because of the fact that $f(t)$ is a continuous function].

Doing integration by parts we get ,

$I_n = F(1) - F(0) -\int_{0}^{1}n.x^{n-1}f(t)dt $.

$I_n = F(1) - F(0) - nI_{n-1}$.

$I_{n} + nI_{n-1} = F(1) - F(0) \cdots (1)$

$nI_{n} + n^2I_{n-1} = nF(1) - nF(0) \cdots (2)$

$n^2I_{n-1} + n^3I_{n-2} = n^2F(1) - n^2F(0) \cdots (3)$

$\vdots$

$n^{n-1}I_1 + n^{n}I_{0} = n^{n-1}F(1) - n^{n-1}F(0)$

Adding and subtracting the alternate equations we get,

$I_n- (-1)^nI_{n-1} = F(1)(1 - n + n^2 \cdots (-1)^{n-1}n^{n-1}) + F(0)(1 - n + n^2 \cdots (-1)^{n-1}n^{n-1}) $

I don't think I am proceeding in the right direction.

Comment: $f$ being continuous, is bounded on $[0,1]$. Can you use that piece of information?

Comment: I dont think so .are we suppose to use mean value theorem for integrals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Stefan Lafon already mentioned, $f$ is bounded, i.e. there is a $C>0$ with $|f(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Hence,
$$
0\leq \left|\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\leq \int_0^1|x^n|\cdot |f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\leq C\cdot \int_0^1|x^n|\,\mathrm dx = \frac{C}{n+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.
$$